# Where can I ask for help finding a resource I've seen before but can't remember where?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm looking for something very specific I read once about unit test reporting for product owners. I'm pretty sure it was in one of the Robert C. Martin series of books and I thought it was in Mike Cohn's book *Agile Estimating and Planning*, although I wasn't able to find it again.

Would a question about this be on-topic on Stack Exchange? Which would be the best site to ask on?

Comment: "...these questions aren't educational in any way, because there's no way to learn about the process of discovery. A particular community member, by virtue of their experience in the field, just happens to be able to take the limited information you remembered and fill in enough of the blanks to guess the correct answer... guessing game questions do not meet our goal of making the Internet better." (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game)

Comment: @gnat "Identify this book/movie/TV show" are allowed on their respective sites.

Comment: @gnat I've just read the whole blog by Jeff "often wrong" Atwood. The respective communities don't agree with him because these questions are still allowed six years later. I remember 90-95% of the details and I want to fill in the gaps to be able to report correctly (demonstration of genuine need). I've searched through six different books, and short of reading them all again cover to cover, I don't know what further research I can do, nor do I understand how I'm being lazy by asking such a question.

Comment: @gnat Never mind. I've found the answer now but because it's only of interest to me I will not share how, or what I discovered, reducing the information available to others. Pity, I thought others might like to know, but apparently not...

Comment: Just to be an outlier, we at Arqade most definitely do **not** allow these questions.  We need something more objective than memory to go off of.  And, honestly, the site's been way better since we did so.  I believe Anime banned it wholesale.  So, while some sites allow it, there are also some that destroy them on site.

Answer (score 3):

While some sites do allow for "identify this" questions, the sites dealing with this particular topic ([Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agile) or 
[Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agile), or *possibly* [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile) or [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agile)) don't.

You'll have to go elsewhere to find your answer. Or you might try the chat on `pm.stackexchange.com` or `sqa.stackexchange.com`.